# Python Tkinter Multithreading functions

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, imaplib

I am currently working on an Email sender and recieving program with the tkinter library from python. 
I am using the threading module to make the program refresh the unread emails every 60 seconds while you can still continue doing stuff in the program.

The threading module works when just making a print("something") command, and I can still continue doing stuff in the program. However, when I make the thread log into gmail and getting the unread email count, the whole program freezes and crashes.

Below is a snippet of my code. I will not post the full code, I made a short version to show how it looks.

EDIT:
Made a small fault in the function. the get_credentials() is removed.

```
import tkinter, re, threading, time, imaplib, too many to list here.
class Application(Frame):

def __init__(self, parent):
        ... Start some functions
        ... Create some widgets
        ... Create some global stringvars for entry fields

def threadrefresh(self):#I want to start this function when a button is clicked

        def multithreading():

            usernamevar = "Username"
            passwordvar = "Password"

            obj = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', '993') #connect to gmail
            obj.login(usernamevar, passwordvar) #log in
            obj.select() #select the inbox
            unread = str(len(obj.search(None, 'UnSeen')[1][0].split())) #get the total unread
            print(unread)
            obj.close()

            time.sleep(3)
            multi = threading.Thread(target=multithreading)
            multi.start()

        multi = threading.Thread(target=multithreading)
        multi.start()

def other_functions_that_do_not_matter_in_this_case():
    ... Creating GUI
    ... Sending mail
    ... Etc.
    ... Create a button with function call self.threadrefresh


def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Maybe tkinter doesn't like multithreads. Tkinter brings an Tk.after method which calls a function after a given time. Maybe that already fits your needs.

Comment: @IchUndNichtDu I prefer to have a thread running in the background. I have had some success with the thread printing a string every few seconds while I could still use my program.

Comment: Tkinter does threads just fine. Use the trace method on a tk.<something>Var. Point it to a function that adds something to a queue which is searched by another thread (see my answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this code actually correct?

You call this in multithreading:

```
time.sleep(3)
multi = threading.Thread(target=multithreading)
multi.start()
```

You are basically telling every thread to create a copy of itself after 3 seconds... I think you are missing the point of a thread. You should probably have a (single) thread running in a while loop that gets data from a [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).

Whenever you want the thread to act on something, you add it to the Queue.

Edit: Example code

```
import threading
import Queue
import time

def f(q):
    while True:
        print q.get() #block thread until something shows up

q = Queue.Queue()
t = threading.Thread(target=f,args=[q])
t.daemon = True #if parent dies, kill thread
t.start()
for x in range(0,1000):
    q.put(x)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Well, I tried this after just running the thread in the background without calling itself again. Also tried a forloop with a time.sleep. If I dont put the threading again in I just call the function again at the end. EDIT: Will try the Queue method though.

Comment: It's definitely the way to go (Queues). You just have a while loop with queue.get() at the top. It will block (the thread) until it gets data. Once it gets data do whatever with it. When it's done, it will loop back and wait on more data.

Comment: Thanks! I did not really know this function existed. I will definetly think of you every time I get a new mail update :)

Comment: Hey, I have been trying some things with Queue but can't realy find an *easy* explanation on the web. How would I construct something like this?

Comment: Maybe something like this: http://www.lonelycode.com/2011/02/04/python-threading-and-queues-and-why-its-awesome/  I suggest just writing some test code that starts a thread that reads from a Queue. Once you understand the principle it's really easy.

Comment: Very nice code, learnt a bit from it and it works like a charm (well, after fixing some python 3.3 syntax things). I have placed it in my Email program just to test how it would run, and it will work, but the GUI completely freezes untill the for loop is over and if longer than 15 seconds the GUI just crashes. I think there is something wrong with tkinter and for loops.

Comment: What do you mean by crash? Does it give an exception?

Comment: Nope, after about 10-15 seconds the GUI just crashes like a Stopped working error from windows. It's not a python crash, it doesn't say anything in IDLE. Before the 10 seconds it's already freezing, unable to press anything. After that it gives the "... Has stopped working" error.

Comment: Sounds like you have an error elsewhere in your code, or it could be a library error.

Comment: It says "Pythonw.exe has stopped working" ,Only does that error if you close the window though. If you just let it sit there freezed, it will unfreeze after the for loop is over.

Comment: All the code is in the function only, there are no external things in the Queue and threading function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31007/discussion-between-ipdgino-and-korylprince)