# tkinter populate treeview using threading pool

Tags: python, multithreading, design-patterns, tkinter

I'm looking for "best" way to populate treeview using threads.
I have multiple mail account which I'm checking for new emails.

My plan is to use `Queue` to store accounts which will be checked
using `check_mail` method. This method will return a list of new
mails.

Can I use another `Queue` which I will populate with new mails and
somehow loop while threads are alive?

Is there any thread-safe, good pattern to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very broad, so this answer will also be.

Generally speaking, `tkinter` doesn't play well with multi-threading. You can do it, but must make sure only the main thread interacts with the GUI. A common way to do this is to use the [universal widget method](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) `after()` to schedule handling of data going out to or being retrieved from background threads, typically via `Queue`s, at regular intervals.

Comment: Is there any good examples? I've found this [one](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm) but it doesn't reflect what I need. There's exactly the same example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860961/python-tkinter-multithreading-functions) but I don't find it useful.

Comment: Something vaguely along this lines is illustrated in the `errorwindow.py` in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18091356/355230) of mine to another question. It's a little tricky because the module is designed to be both directly imported and indirectly spawned as a separate process by the main application. It also only has one Queue, so there isn't a bidirectional data flow. The main takeaway would be to note its use of `after()` to handle the `Queue`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll mark this answer as correct and post (maybe not so great) solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best idea but it works

```
class Main(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):       
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.some_service = SomeService()
        self.some_service.run()
        self.init_gui()
        self.after(60000, self.check_for_updates)  # Use it to run service
        self.after(2000, self.update_gui)  # Update GUI every 2 seconds.

    def check_for_updates(self):
        data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        self.some_service.populate_job_queue(data)
        self.after(60000, self.check_for_updates)

    def update_gui(self):
        if not self.some_service.update_queue.empty():
            update = self.some_service.update_queue.get()
            ## Do something with update ##
            self.text.insert(tk.END, update)
        self.after(2000, self.update_gui)


class SomeService(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.update_queue = Queue()
        self.job_queue = Queue()

    def populate_job_queue(self, jobs):
        for job in jobs:
            self.job_queue.put(job)

    def run(self):
        for x in range(8):
            worker = Thread(target=self.do_something, daemon=True)
            worker.start()

    def do_something(self):
        ## Do something with data
        while True:
            if not self.job_queue.empty():
                job = self.job_queue.get()
                # Do something
                self.update_queue.put(some_data)
```

Comment: A problem with this may be the fact that there's a burst of multi-threading occurring only once every 60 secs during which time the GUI effectively hangs until they're all idle again (because the `self.pool.join()` at the end of `run()` blocks). I think what you want to do is have the threads potentially putting stuff in a queue all the time and have the main GUI periodically (via `after()`) retrieve things from it and update any affected widgets based on them as necessary.

Comment: @martineau Thanks! I've fixed it to match my needs. Haven't tested the example above but I hope it works.

Comment: Looks like the update addressed the things I mentioned. The indentation of the `update_gui()` method is a little off, though. `;-)`